# Flask: two servers supporting WS and HTTP protocols

Tags: python, http, flask, websocket, server

I would like to run two servers in parallel when my application starts, one for `HTTP` requests, one for `websockets` (using python-sockio). I already have a python back-end which starts an `HTTP`-based server with `Flask`. However, every time I start the first server, it seems like it is blocking the thread which in turn, causes my second server not to initialize at all. Since I'm using Flask, is there a `Flask`-way to do this?

Comment: Can you describe which websocket server you're referring to?

Comment: Have you considered `flask-socketio` instead of using `python-socketio` directly. Flask-SocketIo is wrapper around python-socketio. Same creator.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to run the two servers on 2 different ports like so

```
flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000
```

```
flask run --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5001
```

If I did a terrible job explaining try and look at this thread [Python - How to run multiple flask apps from same client machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205495/python-how-to-run-multiple-flask-apps-from-same-client-machine)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your app can serve both websockets and HTTP. Here's a code example taken from Miguel Grinberg's Flask-Socketio [example](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('my event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```